# Using Notepad++ is it possble to create a shortcut to add 2 blank lines indented 4 spaces?

Tags: notepad++, newlines, indentation

I'm working with Python, and while I use PyCharm, sometimes I need to use NotePad++.

Is it possible to create a **shortcut** to add 2 new blank lines, preferably indented 4 spaces? I'm aware of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to add **a new unindented line**.

Comment: Record and replay a macro.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Done

Comment: @DavidPostill, is there any reason not to make your comment an answer?  It answers the question, in that the easiest way to assign a shortcut to that _is_ to record the macro and assign it a shortcut.  And as an answer, it could be upvoted/accepted, and will make this question not show up as "unanswered", when it has been.

Comment: @PeterCJ Done. Answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is it possible to create a shortcut to add 2 new blank lines, preferably indented 4 spaces?

The easiest way is to record a macro. If you wish to reuse the macro you can assign it a shortcut.

> Click the record button on the toolbar and perform the task.
>
> For example, if you wanted to delete every other character in a
>   document, you would click right, right, then backspace.
>
> After doing this once, click the stop button to finish recording your
>   macro.
>
> Press play each time you want this action performed, or click the fast
>   forward button to initiate the action multiple times.
>
> You can even save a created macro for further use, by assigning it one
>   of the many available keyboard shortcuts found under the save macro
>   button.

Source [How to Get More Plus out of Notepad++](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-get-more-plus-out-of-notepad-5686272)

Answer (score 0):

```
Ctrl+M
```

gives you this, but internally it gives you just CR not LF

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: this - is it possible to create a short to add a new unindented line in Notepad++.